# Hosted email routing service while downgrading domain

Tags: email, smtp, g-suite

I'm at a situation where I need to close a domain on Google Apps due to inactivity, while closing the domain I would be interested to preserve emails sent to that domain.

I understand that my options are finding a free / cheap email routing service.

What options are available the mentioned use case?

Answer (score 1):

Setting up a postfix server that accepts this domain might help with what you are looking for. Any low cost VPS server should be sufficient.